# String split based on column (Java)

Tags: java, string, text, format

New to java. I want to read in a file that has lines formatted like this

```
en Fox 3 1344
en Bird 19 144
en Dog 93 1234
```

For each line I want to pick the contents of column 2 and 3. In the case of the first line "Fox" and "3". and display them. So far this is what I have.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class pagecounts {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

       String content = new Scanner(new File("filename")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            *// letter in column 2 and 3 pick code goes here.*

        System.out.println(content);

   }
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each column can contain only one value (word/number) you can use Scanner to read all tokens form one line and use only these which interest you.

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path))){//try-with-resources
                                    //will automatically close stream to file
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        String col1 = sc.next();
        String col2 = sc.next();
        int col3 = sc.nextInt();//you can also use next() if you want to get this token as String
        int col4 = sc.nextInt();//same here

        System.out.printf("%-15s %d%n", col2, col3);
    }
}
```

You can also read file line by line and split each line on space

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(path))){//try-with-resources
                                    //will automatically close stream to file
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");//I assume there are no empty collumns
        System.out.printf("%-15s %s%n",tokens[1],tokens[2]);
    }
}
```

You can also treat this file as CSV file (Comma Separated Values) where values are separated with space. To parse such file you can use library like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) with separator defined as space

```
try(CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path),' ')){
    String[] tokens = null;                           //   ^--- use space ' ' as delimiter
    while((tokens = reader.readNext())!=null)
        System.out.printf("%-15s %s%n",tokens[1],tokens[2]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`:

```
 System.out.println(content.split(" ")[1] + " " + content.split(" ")[2]);
```